# how to give space between two string while concatnating

Tags: iphone, nsstring, concatenation

I am concatenating two string using following way I want space between Added Content To My Learning And the second String any idea how to give space thanks

```
    NSString *firstString =@"Added Contnet To My Learning";
NSString *secondString = appDelegate.activity_Description;
appDelegate.activity_Description = [firstString stringByAppendingString:secondString];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579543/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-iphone/16579565#16579565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
NSString *firstString =@"Added Contnet To My Learning";
NSString *secondString = appDelegate.activity_Description;
appDelegate.activity_Description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstString, secondString];
```

Comment: Or `[firstString stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", secondString];`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
 NSString *firstString =@"Added Contnet To My Learning ";
 // a space after the first string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is all way you can do with string

```
//1st Way
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstString,secondString];

//2nd Way
NSString *finalString = [firstString stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",secondString];

//3rd way
NSArray *ary= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstString,secondString, nil];
NSString *finalString= [ary componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Follow this [how to concatenate two strings in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579543/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-iphone/16579565#16579565)