# how to concatenate two strings in iphone

Tags: iphone, string, concatenation

In this Code here i am sending Code number and phone number seperatly, i have two textFiedls phone code number field, and phone number field, but i want to concatenate code number and phone number field and send it as full mobile number...

Please help me how to concatenate codenumber and phone number.

```
self.operatorLbl.text = self.operatorStr;

    self.codeLbl.text = self.codeStr;

    self.phoneNumLbl.text = self.phoneNumStr;

    self.balanceLbl.text = self.balanceStr;

[post orderConfirm: self.operatorLbl.text :self.codeNumLbl.tex :self.phoneNumLbl.text :self.balanceLbl.text];
```

I'm very very new in this program need your help

Comment: @Sumit Mundra.. happy to see you on SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is all way you can do with string](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/03/operation-on-string.html)

```
//1st Way
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstString,secondString];

//2nd Way
NSString *finalString = [firstString stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",secondString];

//3rd way
NSArray *ary= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstString,secondString, nil];
NSString *finalString= [ary componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append in different way like this...

First Way

```
NSString *combinedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstStr, secondStr];
```

Second way

For Immutable String

```
NSString *firstStr = @"FirstString";
NSString *secondStr = @"SecondString";
NSString *concatinatedString = [firstStr stringByAppendingString:secondStr];
```

For a Mutable string:

```
NSMutableString *firstStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"FirstString"];
NSString *secondStr = @"SecondString";
[firstStr appendString:secondStr];
```

Comment: thanks this is working, but when i click up or down arrow there is a message "vote up/down requires 125 reputation" what is this message ?

Comment: @user2365547 welcome, I know my dear but in this case  you can accept this answer

Comment: @ZeeshanShaikh for upvote you need 15 repo and for down vote you need 125 repo :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
    NSString *string1, *string2, *result;

string1 = @"This is ";
string2 = @"my string.";

result = [result stringByAppendingString:string1];
result = [result stringByAppendingString:string2];
OR

result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"This is "];
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"my string."];
```

If a = AAA and b = BBB then you will need to write

```
[a stringByAppendingString:b];
```

So in your case it will be `[codeLbl.text stringByAppendingString:phoneNumLbl.text];`

For more information about this method please see  [NSString Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/)

If its not helping you please let me know